# Find the average and total revenue by each sub-category for the categories which are among top 5 categories in terms of quantity sold? <SQL Server>

Tags: sql-server

For this question, I have two tables and are as follows :

- prod_cat_info --- This table has the following columns:

  1. prod_cat : It contains the products' category names
  2. prod_cat_id : It contains the products' category ID. Note that every product category has been assigned a unique ID. For example :: Lets say I have following product categories Books,Sports,Electronics. So these 3 product categories will be assigned product category ID as 1,2 & 3 respectively.
  3. prod_subcat : It contains products' subcategories
  4. prod_subcat_id : It contains products' subcategories ID

Now how this product subcategories are stored. For example : Lets say for product category "Books", I have 3 product subcategories like "Novels", "Schoolbooks" & "Fiction". So in this case also, each and every product subcategory would be assigned an ID like 1,2,3 and so on.

- Transactions --- This is another table which has the following columns :

  1. total_amt : It contains amount paid by customer when a transaction took place.
  2. Qty : It contains quantities ordered by customer of a particular product.
  3. prod_subcat_id : It contains products' subcategories ID
  4. prod_cat_id : It contains the products' category ID.
  5. Cust_ID : It contains customer ID [Irrelevant column in case of this question]

What I did is, I break this question into 2 parts & wrote 2 separate queries. Query is given below. I am not able to figure out how to join these 2 queries in order to achieve the output.
For my query1 - I have fetched all the product subcategories.
In query2 - I have fetched the top 5 product categories based on quantities sold.

Now I feel that Query2 can be used as a subquery in Query1 inside WHERE clause.
But It may require some modifications because what I know is that orderby can't be used in subquery & also result of a subquery will be a single output.

Therefore, I need some help on how can I combine/modify this query in order to achieve the result.

```
**Query1**
select P.prod_subcat as Product_SubCategory, 
AVG(cast(total_amt as float)) as Average_Revenue,
SUM(cast(total_amt as float)) as Total_Revenue
from Transactions as T
INNER JOIN prod_Cat_info as P
ON T.prod_cat_code = P.prod_cat_code AND T.prod_subcat_code = 
P.prod_sub_cat_code
group by P.prod_subcat

**Query2**
select top 5 P.prod_cat, sum(Cast(Qty as int)) AS Quantities_sold from
prod_cat_info as P
inner join Transactions as T
ON P.prod_cat_code = T.prod_cat_code AND P.prod_sub_cat_code = 
T.prod_subcat_code
group by P.prod_cat
order by sum(Cast(Qty as int)) desc
```

Comment: Please post tables as create table statements and sample data as insert statements. Making us guess at your table structure and coding without anything to work with is painful. [Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: @SeanLange...Hey Sean.. I do have data in csv files only. Is there any way I can upload those files here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `TOP` operator with `ORDER BY`, which is exactly your case, then you can use order by in a subquery. Because in this case the `ORDER BY` is used to determine the rows returned by the `TOP` clause.
And for multiple values you can use `IN` operator

```
select P.prod_subcat as Product_SubCategory, 
AVG(cast(total_amt as float)) as Average_Revenue,
SUM(cast(total_amt as float)) as Total_Revenue
from Transactions as T
INNER JOIN prod_Cat_info as P
ON T.prod_cat_code = P.prod_cat_code AND T.prod_subcat_code = 
P.prod_sub_cat_code
WHERE P.prod_cat_code IN (
select top 5 P.prod_cat_code
from prod_cat_info as P
inner join Transactions as T
ON P.prod_cat_code = T.prod_cat_code AND P.prod_sub_cat_code = 
T.prod_subcat_code
group by P.prod_cat
order by sum(Cast(Qty as int)) desc
)
group by P.prod_subcat
```

Comment: Thanks @Shikhar Arora. I little tweak to the query You have suggested and it worked. The only changes required are :
1) In subquery use prod_cat as the same has been used in group by in the subquery.
2) Use prod_cat in main query and use the same in group by clause of the main query.
It will work as charm.
Thanks again to help me understand that order by can wokr in a subquery if used with TOP keyword.

Comment: You're right that was a typo sorry. Anyways, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select prod_cat, prod_subcat , avg(total_amt) as average_amount , sum(total_amt) as total_amount
From transactions as t 
inner join prod_cat_info as p 
on t.prod_subcat_code=p.prod_sub_cat_code and t.prod_cat_code = p.prod_cat_code
Where prod_cat in 
(Select Top 5 prod_cat
From transactions as t 
inner join prod_cat_info as p 
on t.prod_subcat_code=p.prod_sub_cat_code and t.prod_cat_code = p.prod_cat_code
Where total_amt > 0  and qty > 0 
Group by prod_cat
Order by  count(qty) desc) 
Group by prod_subcat
Order by prod_cat asc;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).